# Renew access token and protect static files

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

I have question regarding setup of access token renewal/refresh. Our Setup:

- Implicit flow
- Angular SPA using bearer token for API
- Thin MVC frontend serving cshtml containing SPA
- Short access token (10min)
- 20 min Idsrv cookie sliding (used as activity timeout)

The application has to apply to some strict security rules and intellectual property.
We need to renew the access token before it expires and API returns 401.
I’ve looked at the oidc-client-js to handle that. But that would remove the option of authenticating the static files like we do today, since there would no longer be a cookie for the MVC app.

Is there a way of securing them, or is that just something that we have to accept when building a SPA with OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to enforce authorization on static files then this needs to be done by server-side code. Since your client is using an MVC backend, my recommendation would be to use the Hybrid Flow in conjunction with the Katana OpenID Connect middleware. You may then pass on any tokens you would like to use from the server-side code to your SPA via your view (cshtml).

The middleware required is available on NuGet:

```
install-package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
install-package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
```

The following snippet allows for configuration in your OWIN pipeline (taken and slightly altered from [this tutorial](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html)):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://localhost:44319/identity",
    ClientId = "mvc",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44319/",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = "openid offline_access",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});
```

Using this flow, you are no longer given tokens immediately but will need to exchange the auth code returned ("code" grant type) for a pair of tokens being the:

- access_token (the one you are already receiving in implicit flow)
- refresh_token (this can be used at the token endpoint to renew the access_token)

The main things to note about the above configuration are response type and scope.

1. Response type is no longer just asking for tokens (implicit) but now asks for code.
2. Scope includes "offline_access" scope which will return the refresh_token.

Like this we have solved both your access token expiry problem and have begun to solve your static asset problem by moving authorization to the back-end. To help you with the next part I would need to know how you are serving your assets as there are different ways depending on whether you are using OWIN to serve or IIS.

Comment: This is a great answer for the server side.  But how do you get the tokens to the spa?  And once they are there, how do you register them with an OIDC client to get the claims and such?

Comment: I apologise but my answer is actually quite brief. Using the above you are not out of the woods, but these libraries are well documented as well as being faithful to the specifications they implement and I feel that I might be going far out of the scope by continuing to explain.

Comment: Having said that, I have just tried to clarify a bit more in my answer to push you in the right direction. The questions in your comment will be answered once you see how you exchange the code for tokens (saved as claims on your back-end code). You then simply split these out in your view to make them accessible to your javascript. :) From then on you don't really need a full on oidc-client but perhaps just an Auth2 client for handling the calls to the token endpoint (they are simple things you could code yourself, however). Good luck!